# How to extract text between double quotes via a specific tag?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a beginner in writing regular expressions. I am unsure how to extract the text **Paris** from the list in the grey area.

Regular expression I have wrote so far: 
 "text":"(.*?)"

```
{"hashtags":[{"text":"Paris","indices":[10,10]}],"symbols":
[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"Testcurve","name":"Test Garden","id":9999,
"id_str":"999123","indices":[0,10]}],"urls":[]}
```

The result of this regular expression is: "text":"Paris". Please advise.

Comment: Why would you want to access a value from a JSON using Regexp..?

Comment: Have you considered using `JSON.parse` for your problem?

Comment: @ideaboxer no I did not, but will do now. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a valid json string, so it will be much better to not extract it using regular expression, but use the `JSON.parse` for that:

```js
data = '{"hashtags":[{"text":"Paris","indices":[10,10]}],"symbols":    [],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"Testcurve","name":"Test Garden","id":9999,"id_str":"999123","indices":[0,10]}],"urls":[]}';
obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(obj['hashtags'][0]['text'])
```

Comment: I will investigating JSON.parse this afternoon :-) Thank you for the answer above, much appreciated.